# あるフォルダの中のファイルをワイルドカードで特定し、更新日時を取得する

Tags: vba, excel

お世話になっております。
EXCEL VBAで、あるフォルダの中にあるファイル(`C:\TEST\test1234.txt`)をif文にて
ワイルドカード指定(test*.*)でイコールとなったら、ファイルの更新日時を
取得するという方法を実装したいと思っています。

下記記述の方法では、test1234.txt=test*.*がfalseと判定され、更新日時取得の
ルーティンを通りません。

このような仕様を実装したい場合、方法はあるでしょうか。

```
Sub filedate()

Dim fname             As String   '

'wordのcell（1,2）にはtest*.*と入力されている
fname = Worksheets("work").Cells(1, 2)

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set fl = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fl = fso.GetFolder("C:\TEST") ' フォルダを取得
'上記C:\TEST内にはtest1234.txtが保存されている

Set f = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each f In fl.Files ' フォルダ内のファイルを取得
    If f.Name = fname Then  ' 日時を取得したいファイル
        Dim d As Date
        d = f.DateLastModified ' 更新日時を取得
    End If
Next

Worksheets("check").Range("H27") = d
Worksheets("check").Activate
Worksheets("check").Range("A1").Select
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If f.Name = fname Then
```

を

```
If f.Name Like fname Then
```

に変えたら取得できると思います。

Comment: 補足。[第49回.Like演算子とワイルドカード | VBA入門](https://excel-ubara.com/excelvba1/EXCELVBA349.html)

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Comment: Likeに変えたら思った通りの動きをしました。